# Django how to show paginations correctly for each user?

Tags: django

Right now my paginations is same for all user. Let you explain. Assume I listed 2 items per page if user Jhone have 4 items then he will see total 2 page number. see the picture:
[image]

But User Mick haven't any items in his account why he is seeing only page numbers? see the picture

[image]

here is my code:

**views.py**

```
 def ShowAuthorNOtifications(request):
        user = request.user
        notifications = filters.NotificationFilter(
                          request.GET, 
                          queryset=Notifications.objects.all().order_by('-date')
                      ).qs
        paginator = Paginator(notifications, 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            page_obj = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            page_obj = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        
        notification_user =  Notifications.objects.filter(user=user).count()
        Notifications.objects.filter(user=user, is_seen=False).update(is_seen=True)
        template_name ='blog/author_notifications.html'
        
        context = {
            'notifications': notifications,
            
            'notification_user':notification_user,
            'page_obj':page_obj,
        }
        print("##############",context)      
        return render(request,template_name,context)
```

#html

```
{% for notification in page_obj.object_list  %} 
{%if user.id ==  notification.blog.author.id %}
#my code
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

#my pagination code:

```
<!-- Pagination-->       
 <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First Page</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">← Back</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page →</a></li>
    
    {% endif %}

    {% for i in  page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#!">{{ i }}</a></li>
      
    {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and i < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
     
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last Page</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
```

If tried to use pagination inside my forloop but it's showing  page number after each items. How to show paginations correctly  for each user?

Answer (score 0):

I found where I was doing mistake. it was happening for using this queryset `Notifications.objects.all().order_by('-date')` which returning all objects then I use filter for get only correct user object which will prevent showing pagination of others user. here is my updated  queryset `Notifications.objects.all().filter(user=user).order_by('-date')`

Answer (score -1):

In your pagination code,you want to include `has_other_pages` condition

```
<!-- Pagination-->     
{% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}  
 <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First Page</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">← Back</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page →</a></li>
    
    {% endif %}

    {% for i in  page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#!">{{ i }}</a></li>
      
    {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and i < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
     
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last Page</a></li>
</ul>
{%endif%}
```

Comment: what do you mean by has_other_pages??? I have only issue it's showing page same numbers for all user. read  my problems

Comment: @boyenec, `has_other_pages` is a method of **Page** class: _Returns True if there’s a next or previous page._

Comment: NKSM  I think this is not solution for my problems. Right now My pages number showing same for all user. see the two picture above